# Default div height

Tags: css, html

I would like to have a div by default 100% in height `height: 100%;`, but if there contents of the div don't fit, I want the div to dynamically expand.

Comment: Welcome.what have you tried?

Comment: 100% of what though? Is there a parent element with a fixed height?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `min-height` property might be what you are looking for:

Assigning

```
min-height: 100%;
```

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-height

to your `div` will make it have 100% of the height of its paremt-element.
So make sure that the surrounding elements (at least `<html>` & `<body>`) have 100% themselves:

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also set the height to

```
 height:auto;       /* for IE as it does not support min-height */
 min-height:100%;
```